# Is there a way to automatically add "Option Strict On" to all codebehind files created in Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I've been manually adding the following line every time I create a new user control / web form in one of my ASP.NET web forms projects:

```
Option Strict On
```

I can't just set it in web.config because it's a legacy project that has user controls / web forms that would bomb out if we turned on option strict for the entire site, so the current solution is to apply it to all new user controls / web forms and slowly update the older pages.  Is there some sort of Visual Studio setting / template I can change so that "Option Strict On" is applied automatically when Visual Studio creates the codebehind files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your templates are located in

C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\VisualBasic

or

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\VisualBasic

You can modify the name and other file information in your *.vstemplate but you're probably looking for the *.vb code and just placing the `Option Strict On` on top.

Comment: This worked for me with one addition: you need to refresh the ItemTemplatesCache after making the changes.  You can do this by running "devenv /installvstemplates" after making changes to the templates.

Answer (score 2):

To change the default values of Option Explicit and Option Strict in Visual Studio .NET, click Options on the Tools menu to open the Options dialog box. Then, change the default values for Option Explicit and Option Strict in the VB Defaults section of Projects and Solutions.

***EDIT:*** The above applies for VB projects, for web applications try modifying the web.config:

```
<system.codedom>
    <compilers>
        <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.VisualBasic.VBCodeProvider, System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" warningLevel="0" compilerOptions="/optionstrict+" />
    </compilers>
</system.codedom>
```

Comment: Been so long since I did VB I forgot about that option, much easier than doing it by hand.

Comment: Just fyi: doesn't seem to be an option in Visual Web Developer Express.

Comment: Will this apply to all files in my solution or only newly created files?  I mentioned that I can't have this apply to all files since I have older files that need to be left the way they are for the time being.

Comment: The first option should apply to the newly created files.  The second will modify the compiler to compile the entire app in strict mode.  I haven't used the first option in an ASP .NET app, so I'm not sure if it applies.  If it doesn't work, then you will need to make a modification to the templates, as suggested by the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

modify your code templates for vs:

In the folder:  C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\VisualBasic\Web\1033

Just open the zip file modify the contents and rezip.

Same works for other versions of visual studio as well.

Answer (score 0):

Its an old thread, so just wanted to add that for VS2019 I found these options under following folders

For website projects (have templates for ASPX, ASCX etc) under folder

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\VisualBasic\Web\Web Forms\1033
```

For regular class.vb, found it under

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\VisualBasic\Code\1033\Class
```

You can find more templates under root folder

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates
```

Although there is an option on project level, but for old projects, it might not be easy to enable them, as it may require too many changes in existing code. But with these templates, you can make sure that future files have these options enabled. (and you can for sure add more customization)